# Closed down Steam while downloading a game

Tags: steam

I was downloading a Steam game with terribly slow wifi. I managed to downloaded 6.5 gigabytes out of the 12.5 then shut off my computer because I thought steam would pause it (at previous questions asked about it) But then when I get back on I see it say 125 MEGABYTES. Now it says I have 12-14 hours of download time left and I dont have that kind of time. It doesent matter if it can be fixed, I really just want to know if its a known bug or its being fixed by steam, Thank you.

Comment: Did you put the download on pause before closing Steam? If not that might be the reason.

Comment: If it says it only has 125 megabytes left to download, then it's almost done and the download won't take much longer. Assuming though that it's really saying 12.5 gigabytes left, then try this: let the download proceed for few minutes and then pause and restart it. Hopefully this will cause the progress to jump to 6.5 G.

Comment: You know this isn't Steam support, right? We have no insight into whether it's being "fixed by Steam". At best we could say whether it's a known bug, but I don't see how that's really useful to you - you're stuck in the same situation regardless.

Comment: Also you do realize that the duration of the download does not depend only on how much it has to dl, but it also depends on how fast it goes. If steam is saying you have 125MB to go then my guess is you have 125MB to go. The fact that it takes 14h it is probably because a REALLY bad connection (125MB would take me about 10 seconds or so). As a suggestion... don't use wifi for big downloads... just stick a cable in it for 30 min and you are done. I mean... in 30 min you can get to a store, buy a cable, then 30 more min to download. That's 1h (say 2 if you meet a gorgeous girl on the run) < 14h.

Comment: No, im saying it started at 125 MB. I could download that in minutes. Our wifi isnt the best but its the best in our area,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closing steam while downloading an application and resuming the download later without losing progress is a feature that is supported by steam. Steam will pause the download when closed and automatically restart it when opened again.

So to answer your question, this is not a known bug and it isn't being fixed by steam currently.

In order for steam to restart the download it needs to have access to the games **Local Content**. If these files aren't in the file system then it'll have to restart the download. Try navigating to your steam Library folder and see if these files exist. If they do, point steam to them.

If the files don't exist it's possible that your operating system handled them in an unexpected way. This could be the result of countless different variables though. Either way it may be worth submitting a bug request to steam if they aren't there.

**Edit:** I did some more research on this this morning and found a work around that may of use to you. If your Local Content for the game is available in your file system you should be able to force steam to restart the download where it left off last by copying the downloaded portion from your C:\steam\steamapps\downloading\ folder to your C:\steam\steamapps\common\ folder.

[Here's detailed instructions for doing so](https://steamcommunity.com/app/208650/discussions/0/594821545181748202/)